# How can I add a new row to a datatable that I populated with data from a MS Access table

Tags: c#

I created a datatable and filled it with contents of a table in a MS Access database table.

My problem started arising when I wanted to add a new row to the datatable: I get an error that my input array is longer than the columns in the table, so I went ahead and checked using a column count on the datatable only to get a zero.

```
string str = "Select * from Mazda";

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(str, con);

OleDbDataAdapter adapt = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
adapt.Fill(Mazda);
```

I tried adding a row using the same format as the datatable in my database

```
Mazda.Rows.Add(a,b, c, d);
```

Instead of adding the row, this code throws an error

> Input array is longer than the number of columns

How is it possible, if I had already populated the table and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
var newRow = Mazda.NewRow();
newRow["ColumnA"] = "a";
newRow["ColumnB"] = "b";
newRow["ColumnC"] = "c";
newRow["ColumnD"] = "d";

Mazda.Rows.Add(newRow);
```

You can use in newRow either the column-name as string or use integer values as index. Here i have used "ColumnA-D" as column-name only as example.

Comment: Thanks Leon definitely tried that although it seems my table was resetting as it wasn't  static and was going out of scope ,something like that ,not quite sure ,fixed that though :)